# Invalid Object Error while importing table via Custom Query in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, ssas-tabular

In building my tabular model, I am creating my table via a select statement which is selecting from temp tables I created within the same query, so:

Within the Custom SQL query window, I submit my query which:

```
creates 3 Temp tables, 
populates the temp tables, 
selects from the temp tables, 
then proceeds to drop the temp tables.
```

I attempted to run the query in entirety in SSMS and it works successfully, however in Visual Studio, when I enter the query and click "Validate" the error message "Invalid object name 'TempTable1" appears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgdjI.jpg

I have also loaded other tables using different select statements, albeit that don't leverage any temp tables and they have worked successfully.

Am I doing anything improperly? How can I get the select statement that uses temp tables to load the table within my tabular model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a bug with the Analysis Services 1200 Compatibility Level for tabular models. Using the new compatibility level you can import custom queries fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of holding the SQL in the tabular model, you can convert it to a stored procedure and execute it as the SQL statement.  You can then do the necessary work with the temp tables in the SP.  This can be done with a typical `EXEC` statement as below.

```
EXEC YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourSP
```